# Get correct bounds for navigationItem.titleView layoutSubviews

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uinavigationitem, titleview

I have a subclass of `UIView` that I've added to as the `titleView` of a `navigationItem` using the following line of code:

```
self.navigationItem.titleView = tempview;
```

Easy enough. That works fine. My problem is that this `navigationItem` sometimes has the `rightBarButton` updated (sometimes there is no button, sometimes there is one standard sized button, sometimes there is a larger button).

I figured that I could simply use the `layoutSubviews` method of the `tempview` class that I've added as the `titleView` so I put this in:

```
-(void)layoutSubviews {
    [super layoutSubviews];
    self.mylabel.frame = self.bounds;
}
```

This does not seem to work, as it does not correctly resize the titleview when the `rightBarButton` item is updated.

I've noticed also that the bounds do not grow once they gotten smaller, they simply change the position.

I've tried using `setNeedsLayout` and `layoutIfNeeded` but those simply "resize" the view with the incorrect bounds.

I've also made sure that the `rightBarButton` item is set to nil, but the view still does not correctly expand once shrunk.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 4):

configure your view with

```
[self setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight|UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth];
```

(probably in the initWithFrame)

then implement

```
- (void)willMoveToSuperview:(UIView *)newSuperview
{
    [self setFrame:[newSuperview bounds]];
}
```

now you have your view matching the size of the container, and resizing automatically.

Comment: Why is this not marked as correct answer? This is great tip - willMoveToSuperview is the key

Answer (score 2):

By default, layoutSubviews does nothing. You also never change the size of the titleView, so unless a navbar does that for you, it's no surprise that nothing is changing.

Since you're only changing the size of one of the subviews, I don't think autoresize will work, as I'm pretty sure it's triggered when the superview (the one with autoresizesubviews enabled) changes size. I would suggest recalculating the size of the titleview when you change the rightbutton. If it automatically fits when you add it the first time, you could remove and readd it, but I know that's a pretty ugly hack.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of overriding `-layoutSubviews` have you tried setting the autoresizingMask property?

```
tempView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
```

Comment: I tried that and it doesn't seem to do anything different than the `layoutSubviews` approach. Thanks though!